# Lifetime issue with guard pattern on struct with RefCell

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm running into an issue with lifetimes when using the guard pattern on a struct containing a `RefCell`. I was able to reduce my problem to the following (highly synthetic) example.

```
use std::cell::{RefCell, RefMut};

fn main() {
    let f = foo();
    println!("{:?}", f.a);
}

fn foo() -> Dummy {
    let result = Dummy {
        a: RefCell::new(0.0),
    };
    let mut guard = DummyGuard::new(&result);
    *guard.a += 1.0;
    // drop(guard);
    result
}

struct Dummy {
    a: RefCell<f64>,
}

struct DummyGuard<'a> {
    a: RefMut<'a, f64>,
}

impl<'a> DummyGuard<'a> {
    fn new(vec_dummy: &'a Dummy) -> DummyGuard<'a> {
        DummyGuard {
            a: vec_dummy.a.borrow_mut(),
        }
    }
}
```

The borrow checker gives me the following error:

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `result` because it is borrowed
  --> src\main.rs:15:5
   |
12 |     let mut guard = DummyGuard::new(&result);
   |                                     ------- borrow of `result` occurs here
...
15 |     result
   |     ^^^^^^ move out of `result` occurs here
16 | }
   | - borrow might be used here, when `guard` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `DummyGuard<'_>`
```

My questions are:

1. `guard` is not used after the contained value is incremented, so it could go out of scope before `result` is returned (as suggested by the manual drop, which makes the code compile). Why doesn't Rust release `guard`?
2. If I change the implementation from a `RefCell<f64>` to a plain `f64` in `Dummy` and from a `RefMut<'a, f64>` to a `&'a mut f64`in `DummyGuard`, it compiles and works as expected. Why? What's special about `RefCell` here?

---

I'm adding another illustrating example:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}, {:?}, {:?}", foo(), bar(), baz());
}

fn foo() -> RefCell<f64> {
    let result = RefCell::new(0.0);
    let mut borrow = result.borrow_mut();
    *borrow += 1.0;
    // drop(borrow);
    result
}

fn bar() -> Vec<f64> {
    let mut result = vec![0.0];
    let mut borrow = result.iter_mut();
    *borrow.next().unwrap() += 1.0;
    result
}

fn baz() -> f64 {
    let mut result = 0.0;
    let borrow = &mut result;
    *borrow += 1.0;
    result
}
```

Here, `baz` works because Rust knows that the borrow is not used anymore after the value is incremented. `foo` doesn't work because the `RefMut` goes out of scope only at the end of the function, which gives me essentially the same error message as in the other example above. But why does `bar` work? I would expect it to behave the same as `foo` when it comes to lifetimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RefMut`'s lifetime here is lexical, that is, until the end of scope.

Firstly, [`borrow_mut`'s documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html#method.borrow_mut) is clear that "The borrow lasts until the returned RefMut or all RefMuts derived from it exit scope. The value cannot be borrowed while this borrow is active."

As to why:

If a struct has a destructor (i.e. implemented the "Drop" trait), then the struct's lifetime is lexical, because `drop` method in its "Drop" trait implementation will be called implicitly by the compiler at the end of the lexical scope.

If you look at the [definition of `RefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#1497):

```
pub struct RefMut<'b, T: ?Sized + 'b> {
    value: &'b mut T,
    borrow: BorrowRefMut<'b>,
}
```

That is, `RefMut`'s lifetime is connected to (no shorter than) the inner `BorrowRefMut`'s lifetime, and `BorrowRefMut` [implements `Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#1452). Hence the behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aware of the things you explained, but I was hoping Rust would minimize the lifetime of `guard` just as it minimizes the lifetime of a borrow in this situation. I added another example to clarify my question more.

Comment: I don't agree that this represents an exception to NLL. "Non-lexical lifetimes" has always referred to the lifetimes of borrows, not values. `'b` can be as non-lexical as you want, but it's still going to be *used* in `RefCell::drop`, so it just can't shrink to before then.

Comment: @user14278279 I don't know what's your problem, but for your additional example, `let mut borrow = result.iter_mut()`, the `IterMut` doesn't has `Drop` trait implementation, so according to my answer, it just follows NLL. Why `guard` in `foo` has lexical lifetime is also exlained above (something in it has `Drop` implementation).

Comment: @trentcl Agree that sentence is ambiguous amd edited it, but I just mean it looks like exactly lexical lifetime for the programmer.

Comment: The lifetime of the borrow happens to overlap with the lifetime of the variable because it is dropped at the end, yes. However, If the borrow were actually lexical (based on scope), uncommenting `drop(borrow)` would not help (and if you dig up an old compiler and run OP's example with the old scope-based borrow checker, uncommenting that line should have no effect). Your explanation is essentially correct though, so +1.